# Invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference" on my webview app

Tags: android

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.icche.newspaper, PID: 5318
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
>           at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1164)
>           at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$1.run(DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler.java:39)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)

Comment: Have you found any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that at line `1164` of `WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java`, you are trying to invoke the method `getWidth()` on a null `Bitmap` Object.

Check that `Bitmap` for null before invoke that method, and debug why it is null (with `Log.d()` or with `Toast.makeText(...)`)

Comment: How to debug with "console log". I didn't get it.

Comment: @SAK sorry, was `Log.d()`